# javascript - replacing carriage returns in FileReader

Tags: javascript, replace, filereader

I'm reading in an XML file from another website and I need to replace any line breaks that i get in the response with a space, otherwise words will run together.

I tried this...

```
    function myFunction(xml) {

            var counter = 0;
            var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var captionCounter = 0;
            var captionList = new Array();

            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var captions = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

            for (i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
                var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('text')[i];
                var y = x.childNodes[0];
                var txt = x.getAttribute("start");
                //document.getElementById("captionComment").innerHTML = document.getElementById("captionComment").innerHTML + "<br/>" + txt + " " + y.nodeValue; 
                captionList[i] = new Array(2);
                captionList[i][0] = txt;
                captionList[i][1] = y.nodeValue;
                captionList[i][1] = captionList[i][1].replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
                captionList[i][1] = captionList[i][1].replace(/\r\n/g, ' ');
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything, like it can't see there's a carriage return there. Here is the website I'm loading: https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?&v=lo0X2ZdElQ4&lang=en

and although it looks like the caption "I must say I'm very impressed with the way Mary pronounced my name." is on one line, it actually contains a carriage return after the word "way", so I get "wayMary" instead of "way Mary". I saved the code from that page and I can see the carriage return in the file I save, but the javascript doesn't seem to see it for some reason. This of course happens in other places too.

Comment: What is it that makes you think it doesn't do anything? It *will* replace the linefeed and carriage return characters.

Comment: Are you trying it out in HTML, if so, you need to use `<br />` or something. Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Here is a working link to what I'm doing. http://www.personal.psu.edu/pzb4/yti It's only necessary to do Step 2 and Step 3. On Step 2, paste the first sample URL in then click Enter. Then select English from the pulldown in Step 3. After that it will list all the captions below Step 5. You'll see that "way" and "Mary" get stuck together. It's the function myFunction(xml) that reads in the xml.

Comment: i modified my orginal post to include the correct function. sorry for the confusion. this is my life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're looking for `carriage return + linefeed`, and the data appears to have plain carriage returns. Change your replace line to this and it should work:

```
captionList[i][1] = captionList[i][1].replace(/\r\n/g, ' ').replace(/[\r\n]/g, ' ');
```

Comment: that was it! thanks so much, Justin! i'd have never figured that out for sure.